# Refresh picture

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with my javascript.
I want to refresh an image(not a whole page) every 1 second, but that doesn't seem to work.
So this Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            <!--

            function reloadpic()
            {

             document.images["camimage"].src = "test.jpg";
             setTimeout("reloadpic();", 1000);
            }

            onload = reloadpic;

             -->
    </script>
```

and this in my body:

```
<!-- START OF THE PLAYER EMBEDDING TO COPY-PASTE -->
<img src="test.jpg"  id="camimage" name="camimage"  alt="info"></img>
<!-- END OF THE PLAYER EMBEDDING -->
```

Does it refresh your whole page or only your picture with id: camimage?

As now, i have an issue. I have an image test.jpg that only change in bytes (when a new picture is uploaded). But how do I automaticcally refresh it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your browser will cache the image, making it impossible to re-download the image.

Except for if you would change the filename, but I assume that cannot be done, so you can always add something like a timestamp appended to the source of the image. This has nothing to do with the filename of the image, check the ?.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        <!--

        function reloadpic()
        {
         var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
         document.images["camimage"].src = "test.jpg?random=" + timestamp;
         setTimeout("reloadpic();", 1000);
        }

        onload = reloadpic;

         -->
</script>
```

Comment: do `setTimeout(reloadpic, 1000);` to avoid eval

Comment: A timestamp (i.e. `new Date().getTime()`) would be more appropriate as it is possible if the user remained on page long enough you would have a repeat using `random()`.

Comment: Ok, but assume I have an image in my directory that is called test.jpg how is it possible to reload it then as it doesn't have any other numbers behind it? Because I work with a POST method that send a byte array to it and change the image with the byte array.

Comment: Another question is: Does the page completely reload or only the image. As I only need the image to reload.

Comment: Actually, I already had that date behind it, but I changed it because I have to load a picture called "test.jpg" and not one that doesn't exists in my directory. and also: Does the page completely reload or only the image.  As a friend of me asks this and says this is only possible in AJAX

Comment: So can anyone now please help me? Does the page completely reload or only the image. As a friend of me asks this and says this is only possible in AJAX

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood the answer: the date is not part of the filename, it is a GET parameter which is ignored by the server (anything after the ? is ignored). This fools the browser's cache into thinking it is a new image and will change the image. Your file would still be called `test.jpg`

Comment: oh ok thank you very much! Although, My friend says it's not possible to refresh your image with Javascript, but it is with AJAX Is this true or is in this case the whole page reloaded. As he's almost sure he is correct :)

Comment: He is apparently not correct as my answer works fine with Ajax. Maybe he should look into what ajax exactly means.

Comment: I think rogier21 means "works fine `without` AJAX". Changing the image source using javascript is common. This is one way that buttons can be made to change when your mouse hovers (for instance) and this code sample differs only in the timing of its calling (when the page loads and then registers itself to run again after a timer is set). There may be OTHER apsects of your page design which can't be achieved without using AJAX.